# Prevent User from changing related list lookup

Tags: related-list, field-update

I have a related list object through lookup relationship.

When i click on new button on child object in related list, the lookup is prepopulating with the parent Name.

how can i prevent the users from changing the value inside this lookup ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without creating a custom UI for this action, via [Visualforce action overrides](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_customize_override.htm), this is not possible to control in the standard UI unfortunately. Even in the layout editor the option to make the field read-only is disabled. Though if you have a [master detail relationship](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=overview_of_custom_object_relationships.htm&language=en_US) the platform will by default disable edit access to the parent field but only when editing the child record not creating it.

**Visualforce Approach**

Using the Visualforce action override approach linked above, i was able to build a page that resembled mostly the original native page. Of course in your case, it depends on the number of fields you have, though perhaps a minimum for creation is a good thing?

So this is what my mockup started like with the standard UI...

[image]

This is what I was able to achieve with the following VF page used as an action override...

[image]

This was my Visualforce page used above...

```
<apex:page standardController="Child__c">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Child Edit" subtitle="New Child" />
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>            
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Child__c.Name}" required="true"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Child__c.Master__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Child__c.Text_Something__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Child__c.Checkbox_Something__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```